# android programmatically using shape

Tags: android

I am trying to run MainActivity which extends View but its not running. Do i have to use MainActivity extends Activity to run the application because i want to use draw() method in MainActivity class.Can i use it directly or i have to use View instead of activity?.
Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends View  {
     public MainActivity(Context context) {
     super(context);
}
```

Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your main activity (and any other) MUST extend Activity.
If you want to make your own, custom control, just write it (extend view or some of it's descendatns) and put it into your main layout as any other control.
In your custom control you can override onDraw() method if you want.
Take a look at the docs:
[Custom controls](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your activity should extend `Actvity` and you have get your draw image as `view` which is a object of class that extends `View`

I hope this will be usefull to you.

Comment: in your tutorial their is no layout file

Comment: it is complete tutorial friend. try it. then you will realize

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
   ...
   @Override
   protected void onCreate {
      ...
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      ....
   }
}
```

After you `setContentView`, you can reference it by calling `findViewById(<LinearLayout's id>)`. In your layout you can place the view that you want to do the drawing